# Golang: Filter Protobuf Struct fields by FieldMask

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf Struct storing my arbirary json. I need to filter and keep only some fields based on a supplied list of field mask's paths using [fmutils](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mennanov/fmutils#section-readme)

However, it seems to not work on the Struct type, as all of my fields are gone (my struct becomes empty). Code below. Do I need to do something else?

```
package main

import (
    structpb "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/struct"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
    "github.com/mennanov/fmutils"
)

func main() {
    jsonString := `{
                        "field_a": true,
                        "field_b": {
                            "sub_field_b": 99
                        }
                    }`

    myPbStruct := &structpb.Struct{}
    protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), myPbStruct)

    fmutils.Filter(myPbStruct, []string{"field_a"})
    // myPbStruct becomes empty after this step
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with [`fmutils`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mennanov/fmutils).

[`Struct`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) is defined to be `fields: map<string,Value` where [`Value`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#value).

So, you need to prefix your filter(s) with `fields` to filter `Value`'s:

```golang
package main

import (
    structpb "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/struct"
    "github.com/mennanov/fmutils"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protojson"
)

func main() {
    jsonString := `{
                        "field_a": true,
                        "field_b": {
                            "sub_field_b": 99
                        }
                    }`

    myPbStruct := &structpb.Struct{}
    protojson.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), myPbStruct)

    fmutils.Filter(myPbStruct, []string{"fields.field_a"})
    // myPbStruct retains only 'field_a' after this step
}
```

Comment: that works for `field_a`, but for nested fields, looks like it still cannot get the inner value, even if I tried with `fields.field_b.fields.sub_field_b`

Comment: You should review the documentationn so that you understand how the Messages are structured. `fields.field_b` is a `Value` that contains `struct_field: Struct`. As before `Struct`'s contain `fields`. So, you need `fields.field_b.struct_value.fields.sub_field_b`.